# Jenkins unit test connection string not found

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, mstest

My jenkins unit test returned me the following stacktrace

```
<ErrorInfo>
<Message>Initialization method UpstreamBatchTest.Initialize threw exception. System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'DBEntities' could be found in the application config file..</Message>
              <StackTrace>    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[] parameters)
```

However, I have the connection string in my app.config. The unit tests also runs fine on visual studio itself. Would appreciate if anyone can shed some light.

Comment: Is your app.config copied to the output directory from which the unit tests are run?

Comment: would appreciate if you could kindly elaborate on how to do so, is it manually copy and paste or is it from the ide(visual studio) etc

Comment: Try manually copying it and see if it fixes the issue.  If it does, then add a post build step to your unit tests to do the copy.

Comment: How did this proceed?